# Why does my app crashes on using SimpleAdapter to display Listview?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to generate a ListView using SimpleAdapter. I am getting the following errors. Please help me t fix the errors. My codes are as follows along with the error logs.

Code for SimpleAdapter

```
 SimpleAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.contact,new String[]{"name,path"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path})
    {
      @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            { 

final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
//some codes more here

                return v;
            }
    };
 swipy.setAdapter(k);
```

Code of the database where val gets its value

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> swipelistdata() {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts";

SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        map.put("path", cursor.getString(3));

        wordList.add(map);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}cursor.close();
database.close();

return wordList;
 }
```

error logs

```
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at com.example.taskmanager.mycontacts$2.getView(mycontacts.java:228)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 04-23 12:27:52.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20790):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-23 12:30:35.194: E/Trace(21847): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 04-23 12:30:56.864: E/Trace(22037): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at com.example.taskmanager.mycontacts$2.getView(mycontacts.java:228)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
 4-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
  4-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
   04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  04-23 12:31:08.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22037):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-23 12:31:12.453: E/Trace(22134): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Where does the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception occurs?

Comment: Dude you are trying to get the index 1 value which has only one data at index 0.

Comment: val retrieves the data from databse using the following code val=db.swipelistdata();. I guess it occurs there

Comment: are you sure about that : `"name,path"`?

Comment: I have only one row in my table in the database

Comment: @user3256145: Yes. You are trying to get the 2nd value which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mistake is here

```
new String[]{"name,path"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path}
```

Arrays must have the same length. Try this:

```
new String[]{"name","path"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
boolean isPresent = true;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        map.put("path", cursor.getString(3));

        wordList.add(map);
        isPresent = cursor.moveToNext()
    } while (isPresent);
```

Hope this will work. Let me know if it worked or not.